# How to make a button refill a GridView each time it's clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview

I have a dropdown menu in Visual Studio and when a selection is made, a user clicks a button. Then the button fills a GridView.

It works for one time, but if I select something a second time and click the button, nothing happens. How do I make it refresh or do the action again?

Button Click in C#:

```
 protected void ButtonChangeEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRegistrantsGridView"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SELECT");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EventId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownListEvent.SelectedValue;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens? Button click is not triggered or grid does not fill up with expected values acc to ddl selection?

Comment: The first click fills the data based on what is selected in the dropdown (let's say Event1). The second click or any click after, the grid doesn't fill in the diff data (let's say this time we wanted to see Event2).

Comment: Check the value of `DropDownListEvent.SelectedValue` when you click button for 2nd time. I suspect it takes the 1st value from ddl always. This happens if you have bound ddl in `Page_Load` event handler without putting `!IsPostBack` condition check.

Comment: Okay yeah, I see it is giving me the same id during every click, despite being different rows. So I need to add `!IsPostBack` somehow? What would be the structure of that?

Comment: Is that difficult? See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of `DropDownListEvent.SelectedValue` when you click button for 2nd time. I suspect it takes the 1st value from ddl always. This happens if you have bound ddl in `Page_Load` event handler without putting `!IsPostBack` condition check.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   if(!IsPostBack) {
       // bind dropdownlist here
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. At first I wasn't sure what I needed to put inside that, but I moved my dropdown code inside there and now it works.